# Flutter app: Screen size issue - Unable to make the app responsive to screen size changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I built my flutter app using Pixel 2 on the simulator. When I now test it with Pixel 3 XL, the app is not covering the entire screen space.

I had initially used the below to get the screen size:

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double screenHeight = size.height;
```

After facing the problem with Pixel 3 XL, I tried this to get a safe block space to work with:

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double screenHeight = size.height;
    double safeAreaVertical = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;
    double safeBlockVetical = (screenHeight - safeAreaVertical);
```

Yet, I am unable to find a way for the app to cover the entire height of the screen on both devices. I fix for one device size, it breaks for the other.

I have gone thru all similar questions on stackoverflow and referred to a few other sites as well.
But I am unable to solve this problem. Looks like there should be a better way to deal with the issue.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: For reference, here's everything under the Scaffold from one of the screens that's giving me the issue:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[300],
    elevation: 0.0,
    title:  Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            "MAIN",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: safeBlockVertical * 0.03, color: Colors.black87),
            
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black87, size: safeBlockVertical * 0.035,), 
                onPressed:() {},
                
              ),
            
              IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.black87, size: safeBlockVertical * 0.035,), 
                onPressed: () async {
                await _signOut();
                }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),

),

body: SingleChildScrollView (
      child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
                            Container( 
                              height: 0.039 * safeBlockVertical,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 5, 12.0, 5),
                              child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text ('Date: $month $date, $year', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF424242), fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: safeBlockVertical * 0.02),),
                                      
                                    Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text ('$usrname',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF424242), fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: safeBlockVertical * 0.02),),
                                      ]
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height: 0.85 * safeBlockVertical,
                                    color: Colors.grey[100],
                                    
                                    //child: DashBoard(),
                                    ),
                                  ]     
                                ),

                              Container(
                                        //color: Colors.redAccent,
                                height: 0.04 * safeBlockVertical,
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: <Widget>[

                                            Expanded(
                                             child: RaisedButton.icon(color: Colors.cyan[300],
                                              label: Text('Inbox', style: TextStyle(fontSize: safeBlockVertical * 0.02,),), textColor: Colors.black87,
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.assignment),
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                              ),
                                            ),

                                            
                                            Expanded(
                                             child: RaisedButton.icon(color: Colors.cyan[300],
                                              label: Text('Main', style: TextStyle(fontSize: safeBlockVertical * 0.02,),), textColor: Colors.black87,
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.perm_contact_calendar),
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )        
                                          
                                    ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

This code works perfectly on the Pixel 3a XL, covers the entire screen, no scroll. But on the smaller Pixel 2, the page goes below the screen and scrolling is enabled.

Comment: "This code works perfectly on the Pixel 3a XL, covers the entire screen, no scroll. But on the smaller Pixel 2, the page goes below the screen and scrolling is enabled."... you have the whole body wrapped in a SingleChildScrollView widget, but then you don't want it to scroll?... that's not possible

Comment: If I also understand you clearly, you want the content of the page to fit any given device screen, right?

Comment: @samezedi - Yes, for both your questions. I had to wrap everything inside a SingleChildScrollView widget to avoid the 'RenderFlex overflowed' error when the page would overflow beyond the bottom of the screen on smaller screensize (like Pixel 2) and I want the page to fit on any screen size. Also, I tried removing SingleChildScrollView widget, but it did not help. I got the 'RenderFlex overflowed' error, and the page went below the bottom of the screen on Pixel 2, as expected.

Comment: Okay I understand you mean now, the thing is, you would have to user a layoutbuilder, which takes in a context and constraint to determine every screen size cause not all device screens are the same size, So a better way is you could target a certain size which would work on all mobile but in smaller screens you will have to scroll or otherwise, you might have to write a constraint for all screen size, which is a hell of a job.